# Unable to produce a script file in jenkins

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using jenkins for periodically building my node.js application. Whenever i am trying to build my application I get this on console output

```js
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace
FATAL: Unable to produce a script file
java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temp file on /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace
 at hudson.FilePath.createTextTempFile(FilePath.java:1383)
 at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.createScriptFile(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:108)
 at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:57)
 at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:42)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
 at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
 at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary directory in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp
 at hudson.FilePath$17.invoke(FilePath.java:1369)
 at hudson.FilePath$17.invoke(FilePath.java:1357)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
 at hudson.FilePath.createTextTempFile(FilePath.java:1357)
 ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
 at hudson.FilePath$17.invoke(FilePath.java:1367)
 ... 16 more
Build step 'Execute NodeJS script' marked build as failure
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Triggering a new build of job2
Triggering a new build of job2
Finished: FAILURE
```

What could be the possible reason for this?? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permission of the folder in which the script is attempting to create new files /folder. 
The cause may be that the user that you run the build script with, doesn't have permission to create new files inside that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Besides checking permission, also make sure there is free space on the machine your trying to save the logs/execute your jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

`/tmp` folder has permission issue. Given `/tmp` user access works for me.